# How to get years and months data from Spin Buttons to specific cells?

Tags: vba, calendar, formatting, yearmonth

I have created,

**SpinButton1** for **years**  and   **SpinButton2** for **months**
**TextBox1** from **SpinButton1**
and **TextBox2** from **SpinButton2**

"**E2**" from **SpinButton1** and "**F2**" from **SpinButton2**.

When I change the "E2" as yyyy format, it changes the value to **1905** from **2022**
"F2" as **mmm** or **mm** format, it doesn't change any.

How to create "**G2**" as **yyyy-mm** or **yyyy-mmm** format?

[image: It looks something like this]

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

SpinButton1.Max = 2030
SpinButton1.Min = 2021
SpinButton1.SmallChange = 1
TextBox1.Value = SpinButton1.Value

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub SpinButton2_Change()

Dim Mths As Variant
  SpinButton2.Max = 11
  SpinButton2.Min = 0
  Mths = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

  TextBox2.Text = Mths(SpinButton2.Value)

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

ActiveSheet.Range("E2") = SpinButton1.Value

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

ActiveSheet.Range("F2") = TextBox2.Text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I change the "E2" as yyyy format, it changes the value to 1905 from 2022

Passing an **integer** value of "1" to a cell with "short date" format, will return **01.01.1900**. That is so, becasue Excel interprets it as number of days elapsed starting from agreed start time 01.01.1900.

In your case, you pass value of 2022, so Excel counts: 01.01.1900 **+ 2022 days** = 14.07.1905.

> "F2" as mmm or mm format, it doesn't change any.

Similar thing here - you pass a **string** value, so Excel doesn't know if that should be a month of the year.

Solution is to construct the date in format "yyyy-mm-dd" and set the formatting of the output cell to date-like format.

Finally, to solve your problem:

1. I'd use additional procedure to construct the date:

   ```
    Private Sub MakeDate(sp1Val as String, sp2Val As String)
    Dim tempDate As Date

    tempDate = DateValue(sp1Val & "-" & sp2Val + 1 & "-" & 1)

    With Range("G2")
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mmm"
        .Value = tempDate
    End With

    End Sub
   ```
2. Then invoke this procedure in both of your SpinButtonX_Change() triggers like so:

   ```
    Private Sub SpinButton2_Change()
    Dim Mths As Variant
    SpinButton2.Max = 11
    SpinButton2.Min = 0
    Mths = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

    Call MakeDate(SpinButton1.Value, SpinButton2.Value)

    End Sub
   ```

Note, that you pass SpinButton2's value as an **integer** rather than a string. You start **indexing from 0**, so you have to put **sp2Val + 1** while constructing the date (as I already did in the code).

Hope I helped you :)

Comment: It worked perfectly and I love it. Your very detailed explanation helped me a lot to understand the problems. I was very frustrated about my job which is not relevant to VBA or any kind of coding but while I am learning this I feel alive. Thank you so much!